# why i can't write anything to a custom cache table?

Tags: 7, caching

First in mymodule.install I declared mymodule_schema(hook_schema) mymodule_install() and mymodule_unistall()

Where mymodule_schema() is like this:

```
function mymodule_schema() {
    $schema = array();
    $schema['cache_mymodule'] = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('system', 'cache');
    return $schema;
}
```

this worked perfectly and table `cache_mymodule` with the same structue as table cache was created.
But in my code, using this:

```
$cid=some_calcuated_cid();
$cache=cache_get($cid,'cache_mymodule');
if (!$cache){
    $data = some_calcuated_data();
    cache_set($cid,$data,'cache_mymodule');
    dpm('CACHE SET');
else {
    dpm('used cache');
}
```

I always get 'CACHE SET', Now if i change 'cache_mymodule' to just cache, Or remove it, It works perfectly (saying used cache), Am I missing some hook in mymodule?

Comment: Since Drupal 7, you no longer need to drupal_install_schema on hook_install to add necessary tables. it will be done for you automagically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is just a misnamed variable.

Surely

```
$data = some_calcuated_data();
cache_set($cid,$cache,'cache_mymodule');
```

should be

```
$data = some_calcuated_data();
cache_set($cid, $data, 'cache_mymodule');
```

At the moment you're setting the cache as `NULL`, any time it's already `NULL`...probably not what you were going for :)

Comment: fixed it, tnx, but it's correct in actual module

Comment: Hmm very strange, I use exactly the same pattern all the time and I've never had a problem. Have you tried hardcoding a `$cid` to see if it's a problem with the id generation function?

Comment: sorry Clive! really! you were right... sometimes people make crazy mistakes

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create your own table to use the internal cache. Just use cache_set() and cache_get() as documented. This will store the $my_data in the default 'cache' table:

```
// Store $my_data in cache.
cache_set($data_id, $my_data);

// Get $my_data from cache.
$data = cache_get($data_id);
```

Your code snippet should look something like this:

```
$cid = some_calcuated_cid();
$cache = cache_get($cid);

if (!$cache){
  $data = some_calcuated_data();
  cache_set($cid, $data);
}
```

Documentation:

[cache_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7)

[cache_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7)

Comment: You can create custom cache tables if needed, no issues in that.

Comment: i know but i want to learn creating my own cache, tnx for the tip

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. I do realize I answered a bit beside the actual question. I would suggest you break things apart and make sure your variables contain correct data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug this, enable the mysql log which displays all queries executed (you will need a mysql restart)

```
mysqld.exe --log=path\to\log\file\your-log-file-name.log
```

This will give you a clue if the respective sql insert command is actually triggered and executed. And you should also check (via sql) if 'cache_mymodule' is empty or not after the code snippet execution.